# Writing to sysfs entry through an android app is denied in android M

Tags: android, sysfs

I am trying to write to a sysfs entry through an android application using the following lines of code:

```
String command[]={"/system/bin/sh", 
                  "-c", 
                  "echo 0 > /sys/module/lge_handle_panic/parameters/gen_modem_panic",
                 };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

On installing the app in /system/priv-app, it works fine and creates a modem panic in android L. But, nothing executes in Android M.

I am not sure if Android M requires certain SELinux policy permission.

Comment: Have you checked if that file exists at all on Android-M? Have you tried to do the same manually from terminal? Have you checked `dmesg` output after executing that command?

Comment: @SamProtsenko Yes the file exists.
I found the solution. We need to set the SeLinux policy to permissive manually for echo to work in android M. 
COmmand used:adb shell su root setenforce 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set the SeLinux policy to permissive manually for echo to work in android M. 
Command used:
adb shell su root setenforce 0

Comment: Probably not the best solution, as you disable your security completely by doing that. It would be better to write corresponding SELinux rule for your case and leave SELinux in `enforcing` mode. Check `dmesg` output to figure out what is going wrong. See [this](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate.html) document for details on how to write SELinux rules. Though this way requires to modify rootfs image, which may be inconvenient in your case.